# Why Regular Expressions not work correctly?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have 2 strings with such values:

```
String name = "Scripy";
String username = "adil";
```

When I check these strings with Regular Expressions I get `false` value:

```
if(name.matches("/[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ ]+/")){
    System.out.println("Name: true");
}else{
    System.out.println("Name: false");
}

if(username.matches("/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/")){
    System.out.println("Username: true");
}else{
    System.out.println("Username: false");
}
```

The result:

```
I/System.out: Name: false
I/System.out: Userame: false
```

What is the problem?

Comment: why you need  "/" ?remove it its not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `/`, try:

```
[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ ]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is not needed here in regex pattern
Working code:

```
    if(name.matches("[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ ]+")){
        System.out.println("Name: true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Name: false");
    }

    if(username.matches("^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$")){
        System.out.println("Username: true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Username: false");
    }
```

You can refer here     https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html